# What is this problem asking? (Arc length)

Tags: calculus, arc-length

All of the previous questions are asking me to find the distance of a line in between a set of x-values, for example the distance of $y=x^2$ when $-1\leq x\leq 2$. The problem I don’t understand is asking for the length of $y=\int_0^x \tan t\,dt$ when $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{6}$. How do I go about this?

Comment: Bear in mind $y = f(x) = \int_{0}^x \tan t dt$ is just a function as any other.  However you managed to get the distance of $y = f(x) = x^2$ for $-1\le x \le 2$ will be how you manage to get this.  If $f(x) =  \int_{0}^x \tan t dt$ then $f'(x) = \tan x$.

Comment: Arc length is *not* the same as "the distance of a line in between a set of x-values."  It is unfortunate that neither of the Answers explain how to compute arc length, and equally frustrating is how the Question introduces a mention of arc length without relating it to any definition.

Comment: @hardmath The OP needs to define what he means when he says $\textit{the distance of a line in between a}$ $\textit{set of $x$-values}$ and clearly state that that is what he is after. But I read his question as wanting the length of a parametrized curve $y=\int_0^x \tan t \: dt$, $0\leq x\leq \pi/6$, which one may deduce from his second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The arc length of the curve given by  $y=\int_0^x \tan t\,dt$ when $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{6}$ is 
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{ArcLength}(y)
&= \int_0^{\pi/6} \sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}dx \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/6} \sqrt{1+\tan^2 x} \: dx \hspace{4mm} \mbox{ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus}\\ 
&= \int_0^{\pi/6} \sqrt{\sec^2 x} \: dx \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/6} |\sec x| \: dx \\ 
&= \int_0^{\pi/6} \sec x \: dx   \hspace{4mm} \mbox{ since }\sec x \geq 0 \mbox{ on } [0,\pi/6]  \\ 
&= \ln|\sec x + \tan x | \: \bigg|_0^{\pi/6} \\ 
&= \ln \left|\sec \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) 
 + \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) \right| - \ln|\sec 0 + \tan 0| \\
&= \ln \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) - \ln (1+0) \\
&= \ln \left( \frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \\ 
&= \ln\left( \sqrt{3} \right) \\  
&= \boxed{\frac{\ln\left( 3\right)}{2}}. \\ 
\end{align*}  
$$

Comment: Note that the identity $1+\tan^2 x = \sec^2 x$ comes into play for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint** By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$y'= \tan(x)$$